# Enter key not working in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, input, jtextarea, enter

I'm working on a Java Swing application. I have a `JTextArea` inside a `JScrollPane` inside a `JTabbedPane` inside a `JPanel`. I can type in the `JTextArea`, and every key on my keyboard has the desired effect, except the enter key.

Tabs and spaces work fine. When I press the enter key, then type to the end of the line with word wrap enabled, the line is broken where I typed the enter key, leading me to believe that the issue is with how the `JTextArea` is displaying the text. I'm giving the `JTextArea` a new `HTMLDocument`. Note that when I do not give the `JTextArea` a new `HTMLDocument`, the enter key works perfectly well.

Simple code reproducing the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import java.awt.*;

public class Driver extends JFrame {
    public Driver() {
        setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 1 ) );

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        add( tabbedPane );

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea( new HTMLDocument() );
        textArea.setLineWrap( true );

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
        tabbedPane.addTab( "No enter key!", scrollPane );

        pack();
        getContentPane().setVisible( true );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 640, 480 );
        setVisible( true );
        setFocusable( true );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Driver();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm giving the JTextArea a new HTMLDocument"* Why?  `JTextArea` is designed for the display of plain text, not styled text.  Use a `JEditorPane` for this...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: nevertheless, the JTextArea API does not mention that other types of Documents can't be used (although I agree, PlainDocument is what should be used).

Comment: Note that (an) HTML (rendering app.) would typically ignore new line characters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Probably not, nothing said you can't apply a `StyledDocument` to a `JTextField`, but that doesn't work either ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried a JTextPane, with similar results, except it doesn't allow word wrap. I initially used a JTextArea because I'm not super familiar with Swing and it seemed like it would work well with a HTMLDocument.

Comment: @DethRaid I don't recall mentioning `JTextPane`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JTextArea` doesn't understand `HTMLDocument` - it is not intended for styled documents. You will have to use `JTextPane` with an `HTMLEditorKit` so it knows it is HTML. For some reason, you can't supply your own document, but if you get the one from the component it works OK.

```
    final HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane( );
    textPane.setEditorKit(htmlKit);
    textPane.setEditable(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );

    Document doc = textPane.getDocument();
    System.out.println(doc.getClass().getName()); // It's an HTML Document
```

Comment: Now to just figure out how to make the JTextPane do word wrap... But that's another question for another thread.