# Enter key doesn't make line break in JTextArea backed with HTMLDocument

Tags: java, swing, line-breaks, jtextarea

Code below displays text which you can edit, but when you press `ENTER` line break doesn't appear.

Why and how to fix?

This is because [`HTMLDocument`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html) is used as a model. If default model is used, then line breaks are inserted and displayed.

```
public class JTextAreaTry extends JFrame {

    private HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();

    {
        try {
            doc.insertString(0, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
                + "Phasellus tincidunt, neque ac lobortis viverra, nunc erat convallis leo, sit amet varius purus metus ac dolor. "
                + "Morbi pellentesque velit eu ornare pellentesque. "
                + "Sed lectus orci, sollicitudin non nunc in, vehicula mollis massa. "
                + "Sed a est ac arcu auctor interdum. "
                + "Duis at mauris pellentesque, semper massa nec, cursus nulla. "
                + "Fusce sed rhoncus nisl. Sed et sollicitudin mauris, a laoreet nulla. "
                + "Donec interdum volutpat orci, non placerat odio ultrices non.", null);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JTextArea textArea;

    {
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setDocument(doc); // comment this
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        add(textArea);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JTextAreaTry();

        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try looking at [enter key not working in `JTextArea`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28821433/16653700).

Comment: *"This is because `HTMLDocument` is used.."* Why is a formatted text document being used in a component designed for plain text? Why not use a component designed for formatted text instead? Do you understand that a line break in a HTML document will not result in a new line in HTML (unless `<pre>` or similar is used)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JTextArea` is designed for plain text, not styled text. If you are about to use HTML-formatted text, then please consider using [`JEditorPane` / `JTextPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), which have built-in support for HTML (and line-breaking works as expected when pressing the Enter key). Example below:

```
JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane(); 
HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
ep.setEditorKit(kit);
ep.setDocument(doc);
kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<b>Hello world!</b>", 0, 0, null);
```